# TypeError: 'int' object is ubsubscriptable in python

Tags: python, string, file

I am writing a program that looks to see if in a word with three consecutive double letters, like bookkeeping.

When I try to run the program, I get the error, TypeError: 'int' object is ubsubscriptable.  Any reason why?

```
def find_word(string):

    count = 0
    for eachLetter in range(len(string)):
        if eachLetter[count] == eachLetter[count + 1] and eachLetter[count+ 2] == eachLetter[count + 3] and eachLetter[count+ 4] == eachLetter[count + 5]:
            print string
        else:
            count = count + 1


def main():

  try:
  fin = open('words.txt') #open the file
  except:
  print("No file")

  for eachLine in fin:
 string = eachLine
 find_word(string)


if __name__== '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You should post the full traceback.

Comment: This time it’s quite obvious, but please include the exact error message in future questions. Otherwise it’s just wild guessing where the error appears.

Comment: Note that you can write `for eachLetter in string` much like you wrote `for eachLine in fin`. If you also want the index of the letter, try `for index, letter in enumerate(string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop:

```
for eachLetter in range(len(string)):
```

Will assign numbers from 0 to 1 less than the length of the string to the variable `eachLetter`; after this, `eachLetter[count]` makes no sense.

Did you mean `string[eachLetter]`, etc.?

Note that you're also going to get Index Errors; when you get to the 8th letter of "bookkeeping", for example, there's no character 8+5 = 13 to examine and your program would blow up.

Since this seems to be homework, I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to stop looping 5 characters sooner.

Comment: Thank you! To those of you who may be reading the question for an answer, to fix the error, do this:

range(len(string)-1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error:

```
if eachLetter[count]
```

Here `eachLetter` is `int`, because `range` returns list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = open('words.txt')
string = fin.readline()

def find_word(string):
    for string in fin:
        count = 0
        for count in range(len(string)-5):
              if string[count] == string[count + 1] and string[count+ 2] == string[count + 3] and string[count+ 4] == string[count + 5]:
                 print(string)





def main(fin):

    for string in fin:

        return find_word(string)


main(fin)
```

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you explained what the code piece you've provided does.